# How to fix some imperfections of the mesh after mirroring

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

I would like to know how to fix some mesh imperfections after mirroring. The back part of the mesh of my character is textured with the wrong color and I would like to fix it. I tried two different approaches,but they didn't work. Can you give me some suggestion ? I have attached the blender file.

[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauenA4cHQwNzJYRnM/view?usp=drive_web)

[image: mesh imperfections]

Comment: Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for blend uploads and please add some images to your question. While having blend files is nice and sometimes necessary, they should, preferably, be supplemental to the question content.

Comment: No rights to the linked file. I'd have to request it. Upload it to the suggested site.

Comment: Also post some screenshots of the problem instead.

Comment: As suggested above. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your .blend file and also add screenshots showing the problem you are facing, especially that your question is very related to visioning the problem not just reading a text.

Comment: I can't upload it on the blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com because it allows only files of 25 mb max,mine is 80 mb...

Comment: I added a picture to show you the imperfections of the mesh.

Comment: I have uploaded the file here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnqma41mmyhp8hv/ste_new12_.blend?dl=0

Comment: UV map problem. Visible on top of the image editor. From where your model is... I think the best is to try to correct it manually

Comment: I tried. But i havent been able to fix the problem. Can you give a look inside the blender file ?